# How to get NSMutableDictionary count in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, count, nsmutabledictionary

I want to get NSMutableDictionary count in iphone. I want to know how many items are in NSMutableDictionry. I tried these code to find out the solution but, not helped me lot.

```
NSLog(@"Count : %d", [mutableDictionary count]);
```

It is always returns '0'. How to get the count of NSMutableDictionary in iPhone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can find out how many key-object (key-value) pairs there are like so:

```
NSArray * allKeys = [mutableDictionary allKeys];
NSLog(@"Count : %d", [allKeys count]);
```

EDIT

Upon looking through the dictionary documentation, `NSDictionary`'s `count` method (or property) should work as well.  I think you may have been receiving 0 count because the dictionary was empty or nil. I offered my solution because I tend to care more about enumerating the keys than counting the entries directly.

Please consider the fact that you fixed the issue somewhere else.
• By actually populating the dictionary
or
• By fixing a bug where mutableDictionary was somehow nil

I run this test code and get the commented output

```
  NSMutableDictionary * countDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
  [countDict setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];
  NSLog(@"test count %d", countDict.count); //test count 2
  countDict = nil;
  NSLog(@"test count %d", countDict.count); //test count 0
```

Answer (score 11):

`[[dictionary allKeys] count];` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Rakesh",@"Name",@"r@r.com",@"Email",nil];
     NSLog(@"Count : %d", [dict count])
```

Try this

Comment: @RakeshBhatt +1 from me.  I edited my answer after some research into the count method.  I believe the OP had some other issue that has since been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

if you looking to count NSMutableDictionary values for any Array item you can use.

```
NSLog(@"myDictionaryCount %lu", (unsigned long)[myDictionary[@"items"] count]);
```