# Count NSMutabledictionary in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get NSMutableDictionary count in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815375/how-to-get-nsmutabledictionary-count-in-iphone)

How to get `NSMutableDictionary` count in iphone.

Comment: did you mean Dictionary's Key count ?

Comment: Always prefer to ask google than stackoverflow.. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=nsmutabledicitionay+count&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"Count : %d",[yourDictionary count])
OR
NSArray *keys = [yourDictionary allKeys];
NSLog(@"Count : %d", [keys count]);
```